# Windows 2003 - Sharing an NFS mounted directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, nfs

In one Windows 2003 server there's an NFS NAS mounted as a network drive, this works ok, any application running on the server can access the NAS shared directories.

Now, there's an application that must access files stored on the NAS *but* through the Win 2003 server. How can I share that drive, so externally users can access like `\\win2003\my_folder$` (note the $ at the end).

With internal directories I just click with the right mouse button over the directory, then go to properties then go to the "sharing" tab, click share this folder then type in the share name. But with NFS mounted disks the tab sharing does not exists.

Regards,
Leonardo.

Comment: First thing I'd try? Using a supported OS. Windows Server 2003 went EOL 18 months ago.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I cannot do that.